# How to define swagger property that is an unknown name?

Tags: swagger

I need to define a swagger property that doesn't have a known name.

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
      "?????": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": { "$ref": "#/definitions/ModelRelease" }
      }
}
```

The ????? portion of my definition is an integer of an unknown value. Any ideas?

Comment: how will you be referencing the property later if you don't know the integer?

Comment: It's just an object... flip through them I suppose

Comment: Then does it matter what you call it as long as you store than property name in a variable for later reference (if you're needing to know you've reached this specific property name)?

Comment: I think you can simply use  `"properties": {
      "400": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": { "$ref": "#/definitions/ModelRelease" }
      },`

Comment: You could use `additionalProperties` to define a hashmap ("?????" being a key in this hashmap without the need to define it): 
{
  "type": "object",
  "additionalProperties": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": { "$ref": "#/definitions/ModelRelease" }
}
The downside is that this hashmap can have more than one item.
Could you give some detail about your use case? (it looks really strange)

Comment: @ArnaudLauret Your comment seems to be the only acceptable solution right now. It seems as though Swagger may implement the ability in the future.. allowing for the specification of dynamic keys... but not yet. I think it's called patternProperties or something.

Comment: @Nicholas OpenAPI (Swagger) use a subset of JSON Schema to describe objects. JSON Schema propose `patternProperties` (allow to define a property which name is based on a regex) but OpenAPI current version do not support them. An issue is open to include that in next version: https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/687

Comment: Yep... perfect thanks. If you put that response in an actual answer, I will use it as the accepted response.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You could use `additionalProperties` to define a hashmap ("?????" being a key in this hashmap without the need to define it):

```javascript
{ 
  "type": "object", 
  "additionalProperties": { 
    "type": "array", 
    "items": { 
      "$ref": "#/definitions/ModelRelease" 
    }
  }
}
```

In the general case, hashmaps can have an arbitrary number of items, but you can use `minProperties` and `maxProperties` to limit the item count. For example, if your object must have just one property:

```javascript
{ 
  "type": "object",
  "additionalProperties": {
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/ModelRelease" 
    }
  },
  "minProperties": 1,
  "maxProperties": 1
}
```

Comment: FWIW, this answer is version dependent: swagger (aka OpenAPI 2) doesn't support `additionalProperties`. https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/